# How to build space separated, escaped full paths of files recursively matching glob?

Tags: shell, filenames, quoting

I have a program which requires paths to files as arguments, which cannot be quoted and must not depend on working dir. Can this be done without chaining multiple `xargs`, `tr`, `find`, `readlink`s?

Example output for "*.csv" files: `/home/user/a\ b.csv /home/user/my\ dir/c\ d\$2.csv`

Comment: if you quote an argument the program does not see or recognize this, e.g. `/home/user/a\ b.csv` is the same as `"/home/user/a b.csv"` for the program (if you enter it in a shell)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For passing file paths as arguments to a command, [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) does this on its own with its [`-exec` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Multiple-Files) without any `xargs` trickery:

```
find /home/user -name '*.csv' -exec yourcommand '{}' +
```

That will find every file called `*.csv` in `/home/user` and then execute `yourcommand /home/user/a\ b.csv /home/user/my\ dir/c\ d\$2.csv ...` with all of the found files as arguments. Each file found is passed as a separate complete argument to the program, so there is no escaping or anything else required: `yourcommand` gets many arguments which are each exactly the complete file path.

Another approach is that some shells ([`zsh` in particular](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_2.html)) support more advanced globbing, where you could just write:

```
yourcommand **/*.csv
```

and get exactly the above effect too.

---

**If you really do want the escaped strings themselves**, rather than to run a command directly, you can use `bash`'s [built-in `printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-printf):

```
find /home/user -name '*.csv' -exec bash -c 'printf "%q " "$@"' dummy '{}' +
```

The `%q` format specification expands to a shell-escaped version of the string argument. With many arguments `printf` repeats the format string for all of them, so this produces space-terminated escaped strings of all the arguments to the `bash -c` command. `dummy` is used as the value of `$0`, and `"$@"` gives `printf` all the rest of the arguments, which are your (intact) file names. For your example this would output exactly `/home/user/a\ b.csv /home/user/my\ dir/c\ d\$2.csv`.

Comment: Note that `printf %q` originated in `ksh93` and is also available in `zsh`. Like the `:q` zsh modifier, it will also use `$'...'` for some characters.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
print -r -- **/*.csv(D:a:q)
```

Note that some characters (like newline, tab or non-printable ones) are rendered with the `$'...'` notation which may be a problem for you.

Another approach is:

```
print -r -- *.csv(e/'REPLY=${(qq)REPLY:a}'/)
```

Where all the file paths are single-quoted.

Comment: Can you explain that `(D:a:q)` a bit? What does that mean? Where can I find documentation on that?